# firebase image does not load when used with Image()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, html5-canvas, firebase-storage

so, I have this function

```
async function getAverageRGB(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let context = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.crossOrigin = "";
    img.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1);
      resolve(context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data.slice(0, 3));
    };
  });
}
```

and it works fine when the src is a local file but it just does not work when i use a firebase storage url for eg :

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/marsfood-image-storage.appspot.com/o/userdata%2Fimages%2Fdishes%2F26.jpg?alt=media&token=abed73cd-0ffe-4007-8dd5-5aa42135b8eb

any solutions to this?

When checking for errors with

```
image.onerror = console.error
```

I get :

> isTrusted :  true bubbles :  false cancelBubble :  false cancelable :
> false composed :  false currentTarget :  null defaultPrevented :
> false eventPhase :  0 path :  [img] returnValue :  true srcElement :
> null target :  null timeStamp :
> 7831.39999999851 type :  "error" [[Prototype]] :  Event AT_TARGET :  2 BUBBLING_PHASE :  3 CAPTURING_PHASE :  1 NONE :  0 bubbles :  (...)
> cancelBubble :  (...) cancelable :  (...) composed :  (...)
> composedPath :  ƒ composedPath() currentTarget :  (...)
> defaultPrevented :  (...) eventPhase :  (...) initEvent :  ƒ
> initEvent() path :  (...) preventDefault :  ƒ preventDefault()
> returnValue :  (...) srcElement :  (...) stopImmediatePropagation :  ƒ
> stopImmediatePropagation() stopPropagation :  ƒ stopPropagation()
> target :  (...) timeStamp :  (...) type :  (...) constructor :  ƒ
> Event() Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) :  "Event" get bubbles :  ƒ
> bubbles() get cancelBubble :  ƒ cancelBubble() set cancelBubble :  ƒ
> cancelBubble() get cancelable :  ƒ cancelable() get composed :  ƒ
> composed() get currentTarget :  ƒ currentTarget() get defaultPrevented
> :  ƒ defaultPrevented() get eventPhase :  ƒ eventPhase() get path :  ƒ
> path() get returnValue :  ƒ returnValue() set returnValue :  ƒ
> returnValue() get srcElement :  ƒ srcElement() get target :  ƒ
> target() get timeStamp :  ƒ timeStamp() get type :  ƒ type()
> [[Prototype]] :  Object

Comment: _"The code does not throw any errors"_... you aren't checking for any. Tried adding `img.onerror = console.error`?

Comment: @Phil edited to contain the error

Comment: So the image fails to load. The `error` event doesn't contain details unfortunately so use your browser dev tools _Console_ and _Network_ panels to see what the problem is